# Pepper Development compatibility and versions

Tags: pepper

New pepper support android SDK, but it only supports Pepper 1.9 with LPT_200AR Tablet.

There are also 1.6, 1.6b, 1.8 1.8b versions of Pepper with slightly different OS compatibility and hardwares.

Is there any table or compatibility document how far each versions can go?
Also, is there any upgrade program to existing pepper users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a summary of the three different Pepper versions [here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/family/pepper_technical/pepper_versions.html), which I'll reproduce below. You can find more details on particular sensors / computer specs [here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/family/pepper_technical/index_pep.html).

#### Pepper 1.8 (newest)

- **4 holes** at base of skull
- a camera on the top of the tablet
- **LPT200** tablet model
- **3 buttons** behind the right side of the tablet

#### Pepper 1.8a

- **2 holes** at base of skull
- a camera on the top of the tablet
- **LPT200** tablet model
- **3 buttons** behind the right side of the tablet

#### Pepper 1.6 (oldest)

- **2 holes** at base of skull
- **No** camera on the top of the tablet
- **LPT100** tablet model
- **2 buttons** behind the right side of the tablet

[image]

### Pepper compatibility

As you say, Peppers with the LPT200 tablet (1.8 and 1.8a) are compatible with the Android OS (NAOqi 2.9). The Choregraphe version of the OS for Peppers 1.8 and 1.8a is NAOqi 2.5. I'm unsure about Pepper 1.6.

It's technically possible to upgrade a Choregraphe 1.8/1.8a Pepper to Android, but the availability/process for doing this depends on your region. Your best bet would be to get in contact with your local Aldebaran/Softbank Robotics team and ask them about the possibility of an upgrade. The Choregraphe / Android OSs each have different advantages and typical use cases, so it depends a bit how and for what you want to use Pepper.

Comment: Thanks. I already checked with their official specs. The specific questions are -what Pepper 1.9 means, and -Any possibility to upgrade from 1.6b?

Comment: I don't believe there is a 1.9 version of Pepper yet. 1.8 is the newest. What sort of upgrade are you seeking to do to Pepper 1.6? To the android OS or to a newer Choregraphe OS?

Comment: To the android OS. If possible, I will happily order LPT200 and upgrade. Since my purpose is face recognition, analysis and using some ML models, android seems to fit better.

Comment: Depending on your ML application - I'd suggest the Android version not be the best fit due to being disconnected from most of the robot's hardware. For example, doing vision processing, there's a fairly significant delay with transfering images from the CPU in the head to the tablet (for processing in your Android app). And not all sensors are exposed to the Android APIs. The main advantage of the Android version is being able to develop more robust and full-featured tablet experiences (in Choregraphe OS typically done through web apps).

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to buy a new tablet and retrofit that to a 1.6 Pepper to allow upgrading to Android, if that's what you mean. But again, the process differs by region so your local SBR team would be better placed to help.

Answer (score 2):

Irrespective of the region, it is not possible to upgrade the tablet of a Pepper 1.6b to a LPT200 in order to get a Pepper able to run the Naoqi 2.9 OS (Android version).